# Mime type rendering requires nbformat>=4.2.0

Tags: python-3.x

Cannot use df.iplot. The error it generates is Mime type rendering requires nbformat>=4.2.0. Any help?

Comment: I had a similar problem and it went away after updating all my packages (conda update --all).

Answer (score 2):

Simply update your jupyter notebook version with `pip install notebook`, restart kernel and you should be fine. Had this issue myself and this solved the problem.